# unable to bulk collect into table from PLSQL table type?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

```
SELECT *   BULK COLLECT INTO CONNECT_RET_ITEM_DETAIL FROM TABLE(RET_ITEM_IN);
```

Here `RET_ITEM_IN` is an instance of the table type `RET_ITM_DTL_TMP`;

```
desc RET_ITM_DTL_TMP;

-------------------------------- 
 TYPE RET_ITM_DTL_TMP AS   OBJECT   (
    ITEM_ID       VARCHAR2(50),
    ITEM_DESC     VARCHAR2(50),
    ORDER_NUMBER  VARCHAR2(50),
    PARCEL_NUMBER VARCHAR2(50),
    STORE_NUMBER  VARCHAR2(50),
    QUANTITY      NUMBER ) ;  


desc CONNECT_RET_ITEM_DETAIL

Name          Null Type         
------------- ---- ------------ 
 ITEM_ID            VARCHAR2(50) 
 ITEM_DESC          VARCHAR2(50)  
 ORDER_NUMBER       VARCHAR2(50)  
 PARCEL_NUMBER      VARCHAR2(50)  
 STORE_NUMBER       VARCHAR2(50)
 QUANTITY           NUMBER
```

I can successfully bulk collect in the following cases:

1. Object to object
2. Table to object
3. Table to table

However failing in object to table type insert. Getting the following error:

> Error(118,6): PLS-00403: expression 'CONNECT_RET_ITEM_DETAIL' cannot
>   be used as an INTO-target of a SELECT/FETCH statement

Comment: I tried this as well but no help : 
FORALL i IN RET_ITEM_IN.first .. RET_ITEM_IN.last INSERT INTO CONNECT_RET_ITEM_DETAIL VALUES RET_ITEM_IN(i);

Comment: Is CONNECT_RET_ITEM_DETAIL a database table? If not, what is it?

Comment: No, you cannot `bulk collect` into a table. Use either `insert into .. select from` statement or `forall` construct. `I can successfully bulk collect in 3. Table to table` If we are talking about db table, then no, you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this fully solves your problem, but maybe this code wil be useful. Create table like here:

```
create table CONNECT_RET_ITEM_DETAIL of RET_ITM_DTL_TMP;
```

Next this PL/SQL worked for me:

```
declare
  type RET_ITM_DTL_TBL is table of RET_ITM_DTL_TMP;
  RET_ITEM_IN RET_ITM_DTL_TBL;
begin
  RET_ITEM_IN := RET_ITM_DTL_TBL(
      RET_ITM_DTL_TMP ('a11', 'a12', 'a13', 'a14', 'a15', 11), 
      RET_ITM_DTL_TMP ('b11', 'b12', 'b13', 'b14', 'b15', 21),
      RET_ITM_DTL_TMP ('b21', 'b22', 'b23', 'b24', 'b25', 22) );

  FORALL i IN RET_ITEM_IN.first .. RET_ITEM_IN.last 
    INSERT INTO CONNECT_RET_ITEM_DETAIL VALUES RET_ITEM_IN(i);
end;
```